# Find a replace string in xml file with python

Tags: python, replace

I'm trying to replace a string in an xml file with python. For example:

I want to change enabled to disbabled in:

```
<s:global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled"/>
```

Is it best to search and replace the whole line? Or is there a way to just replaced the enabled on the line if I find a line that matches?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple way could be:

```
for line in fileh:
    line = line.replace("enabled", "disabled")
    ouf.write(line)
```

You do not need to explicitly find "enabled" in the string before replacing it.

However, since its an xml file, I would suggest using the xml parser to modify it.

Comment: This looks like it should work, but what is ouf.write exactly? I can't find anything on it, typo?

Comment: Outf is a file handle for a temporary file. Once you are done with the replace process, you delete the old file and rename the temporary file.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `string.replace()`:

```
for line in whateverXMLText.splitlines(): # or whatever arbitrary loop
    if line.find("enabled") > -1:
        print "Replacing 'enabled' on line: %s" % line
        line.replace("enabled", "disabled")
```

A better solution though, may be to use an xml parser ([`xml.dom.minidom`](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.dom.minidom.html)), and change the attribute during parsing.