# How can I find a replace a string in an .odt file in Python and output it to another .odt file?

Tags: python, elementtree, odt, opendocument

Let's say I have an .odt file called "myfile.odt" in a specific directory (that's not the current working directory) and I want to replace "astring" by "anewstring", then export the modified file into a new .odt file in the current directory. How can I do that in Python?

I tried doing this with XML.Etree, but it was a bit too much for me to understand and I hit several walls, not really understanding what I did wrong. I also tried the solution provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7799382/find-a-replace-string-in-xml-file-with-python), but to no avail... Actually, none of the solutions from other posts managed to do it for me, ChatGPT is of no help either, and I'm struggling as I'm not used to manipulating XML-like files, which, if I understand correctly, is the appropriate way of considering and handling .odt and Word documents generally speaking.

Any tip would be great! Thanks a lot!

**EDIT**: apparently considering the .odt file as a text file does not work (the new file is written but is identical to the input file). Also, the [odfpy](https://pypi.org/project/odfpy/) library does not seem to work either due to a problem explained [on their Git page](https://github.com/eea/odfpy/wiki/ReplaceOneTextToAnother). Anyone who could be able to provide an XML.Etree method (or any method that actually works) would be so kind...

**EDIT 2**: Here is the script I used to try to handle the file as a simple .txt file, but it resulted is the output file being corrupt and unusable, which leads me to believe that XML.Etree might be more suitable:

```
f1 = open('test.odt', 'r', encoding='latin') 
f2 = open('newfile.odt', 'w') 
for line in f1: 
    f2.write(line.replace('mystring', 'newstring')) 
f1.close() 
f2.close()
```

Comment: new = original.replace("old string", "new string"). You might be able to get away with just ignoring the structure etc. XML is "just" text, you don't _have_ to treat it as XML

Comment: Oh dear! So you mean that a good old "with open("myfile.odt") as f" would do the trick? I'll try this right away!

Comment: Check these techniques [file](https://pythonexamples.org/python-replace-string-in-file/)

Comment: @PaulCollingwood, well, it seems to parse and write to the new file without any problem reported, but I cannot open the new .odt file with LibreOffice, it says that the file is corrupt. Here is my script:

f1 = open('test.odt', 'r', encoding='latin')
f2 = open('newfile.odt', 'w')
for line in f1:
    f2.write(line.replace('mystring', 'newstring'))
f1.close()
f2.close()

Any idea?

Comment: An .odt file is not a plain text file. It is a zip container. Inside it there are text (XML) files:  https://opensource.com/article/22/8/odt-file

Comment: The link does not work, but I get the idea, thank you! And yes, I did understand that I have to use a method adapted to XML-like files, but the real question is how to do it. As mentioned in my original post, I'm struggling to understand how XML.Etree works, hence my request for help here. : )

Comment: 1) Sorry about the bad link. Better: https://opensource.com/article/22/8/odt-files 2) So far you haven't shown us any XML file or any attempts at processing it using ElementTree. It is not clear what the difficulty is.

Comment: Well, I would just like to have an example script which would open an .odt file, look for the instances of a given string, replace them with another string, then save the output to a new .odt file. I did not show any attempt because I have no idea how to do that, and re-using various scripts found online did not provide any satisfying result... I just thought it would be a relatively straightforward operation that would be solved easily by people who know how to handle XML files... : /